# XmlSimple - using xml_in() to parse data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hash, xml-simple

I have a simple XML file like this:

```
    <Course>
     <CompanyName value="Ford"/>
     <DepartmentName value="assessments"/>
     <CourseName value="parts"/>
     <Result>
      <CoreData>
      <Status value="completed"/>
```

In my controller I have:

```
    def xml_facil
      require 'xmlsimple'
      config = XmlSimple.xml_in("#{Rails.root}/doc/TestResults/Ford/assessments/mike.xml", { 'KeyAttr' => 'value' })
      @results = config['CourseName']
    end
```

In my view I have:

```
    <%= render @results %>
```

but the error I get is:

```
    undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass
```

I guess my method is returning nil here so how do I fix this so my view will render "parts"?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it's returned nil because XmlSimple() did not read the value key in the 'CourseName' tag.  I switched to Nokogiri and used a similar method and it rendered  <CourseName value="parts"/> in the view.  Now I need to figure out how to capture just the "parts" string without the tag.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've switched to Nokogiri, you can dig out the `value` attribute that you're interested in with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc   = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/doc/TestResults/Ford/assessments/mike.xml").read)
value = doc.at('CourseName').attr('value')
```

Comment: This worked - thanks for all your help.  The controller method is now doc.xpath('//Course').map do |i| 
     {'CourseName' => i.xpath('CourseName').attr('value')} end